# Is it possible to develop an Xamarin Forms app with only Xamarin Studio for MAC?

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to create a new application for Iphone with Xamarin? Forms
Is it possible to do this without any windows system?
I know this sounds bizare but that is the requirment.

Comment: The documentation on this topic is pretty good: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/installation?tabs=windows#development-system-requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can develop Android and iOS apps with Visual Studio for Mac. Of course you won't be able to develop UWP apps.

> With Visual Studio for Mac you can build websites with ASP.NET Core and apps using .NET Core, games with Unity, and **mobile apps for Android and iOS using Xamarin**. (emphasis mine, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/))

Answer (score 0):

As far as xamarin is concerned, you can do just as much with the Mac version as with Windows. You just can not develop a Windows Phone app on the Mac.